# gcloud app engine laravel application cron job not executing

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron, gcloud

I've set up a cron.yaml file following the google cloud documentation. 
Then I created a route in my application, connected with a controller.

This controller runs "php artisan schedule:run" and in the Kernel.php file there is specified what it has to do. In this case, it should send me a mail with some information, but it never gets sent. I ran it in Tinker and it did send the mail, so the problem shouldn't be in there.

In the cron job tab of App Engine, it says the status is failed. When I follow the logs of the application, it does the call to the specified route, but returns a 302 HTTP response.

cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: "laravel cron"
  url: /opdrachten/cron
  schedule: every 1 mins
  timezone: Europe/Brussels
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/opdrachten/cron', 'JobController@cron');
```

JobController.php

```
public function cron() {
    Artisan::call('schedule:run');
}
```

app/Console/Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function() {
        $job = Job::all()[0];
        Mail::to('myemail@gmail.com')
            ->send(new JobFinished($job));
    })->timezone('Europe/Brussels')->dailyAt('08:00');
}
```

Expected result is that the mail gets sent daily at 8 am thanks to the cron job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you manually make a request to `/opdrachten/cron` (try it from an incognito session, to make sure your environment doesn't interfere)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Hi, thanks for responding. I hadn't actually thought about manually sending the request. Firstly I stumbled on a typo and after that I found that my auth guard was redirecting, thus responding with a 302. I've got it working now, thank you!